# The "LinkAssemblies" task failed unexpectedly on build solution in Release mode

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

My project is building successfully on the `Debug` mode, but when I change it to the `Release` mode; the following exception is coming:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State 
    Error       The "LinkAssemblies" task failed 
    unexpectedly.Java.Interop.Tools.Diagnostics.XamarinAndroidException: error 
    XA2006: Could not resolve reference to 'Android.Views.KeyboardShortcutGroup' 
    (defined in assembly 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat, 
    Version=1.0.0.0,Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null') with scope 
    'Mono.Android,Version=0.0.0.0, 
    Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=84e04ff9cfb79065'.When the scope is 
    differentfromthe defining assembly, it usually means that the type is 
    forwarded.---> Mono.Cecil.ResolutionException: Failed to 
    resolveAndroid.Views.KeyboardShortcutGroup   
    at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkType(TypeReference reference)   
    at MonoDroid.Tuner.MonoDroidMarkStep.MarkType(TypeReference reference)   
    at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkGenericArguments(IGenericInstance 
    instance) 
    at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.GetOriginalType(TypeReference type)
    at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkType(TypeReference reference)
    at MonoDroid.Tuner.MonoDroidMarkStep.MarkType(TypeReference reference)
    at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkMethodBody(MethodBody body)
    at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessMethod(MethodDefinition method)
    at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessQueue()
    at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.Process()
    at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.Process(LinkContext context)
    at Mono.Linker.Pipeline.Process(LinkContext context)
    at MonoDroid.Tuner.Linker.Run(Pipeline pipeline, LinkContext context)
    at MonoDroid.Tuner.Linker.Process(LinkerOptions options, LinkContext& 
    context)
    at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.Execute(DirectoryAssemblyResolver 
    res)
    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
    at Java.Interop.Tools.Diagnostics.Diagnostic.Error(Int32 code, Exception 
    innerException, String message, Object[] args)
    at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.Execute(DirectoryAssemblyResolver 
    res)
    at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.Execute()
    at 
    Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.
    ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
    at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.
    <ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext()
```

Comment: What is your target android version (within the Android project properties under **Compile using Android version**)? You may need to increase it to API 24 since [KeyboardShortcutGroup](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyboardShortcutGroup.html) was not introduced until API 24.

Comment: @hvaughan3 hey thanks man. i updated my api and the problem has been solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to increase your target android version (within the Android project properties under Compile using Android version) to API 24 since `KeyboardShortcutGroup` was not introduced until API 24.

Comment: Hi,
I've the same problem but I can't update to API 24. There is another way to solve the problem?
This is my question: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45417829/xamarin-mediaplugin-and-different-android-version)

Thanks!