# Xamarin MediaPlugin and different Android version

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, prism

I have a problem with [Media Plugin](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin).
If the compilation target is Android 6.0 it works fine in debug mode in my device that is V. 5.0.1. The problem is that when I compile in Release mode I receive this error:

```
> Java.Interop.Tools.Diagnostics.XamarinAndroidException: error XA2006: Could not resolve reference to 'Android.Views.KeyboardShortcutGroup' (defined in assembly 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null') with scope 'Mono.Android, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=84e04ff9cfb79065'. When the scope is different from the defining assembly, it usually means that the type is forwarded. ---> Mono.Cecil.ResolutionException: Failed to resolve Android.Views.KeyboardShortcutGroup
   in Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkType(TypeReference reference)
   in MonoDroid.Tuner.MonoDroidMarkStep.MarkType(TypeReference reference)
   in Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkGenericArguments(IGenericInstance instance)
   in Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.GetOriginalType(TypeReference type)
   in Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkType(TypeReference reference)
   in MonoDroid.Tuner.MonoDroidMarkStep.MarkType(TypeReference reference)
   in Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkMethodBody(MethodBody body)
   in Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessMethod(MethodDefinition method)
   in Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessQueue()
   in Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.Process()
   in Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.Process(LinkContext context)
   in MonoDroid.Tuner.MonoDroidMarkStep.Process(LinkContext context)
   in Mono.Linker.Pipeline.Process(LinkContext context)
   in MonoDroid.Tuner.Linker.Process(LinkerOptions options, LinkContext& context)
   in Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.Execute(DirectoryAssemblyResolver res)
```

I [read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44086909/the-linkassemblies-task-failed-unexpectedly-on-build-solution-in-release-mode) that the problem is solved if I will update the compile version to Android 7 (API 24), but after this my action button doesn't work fine. When I tap the button to open the camera I receive this error:

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.XmlResourceParser android.content.pm.ProviderInfo.loadXmlMetaData(android.content.pm.PackageManager, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
```

What I can do? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried also updating all the Android Support Library NuGet packages?

Comment: It's all updated to the last version

Comment: I would suggest creating a brand new project, update all libraries to the latest version, install Media Plugin, and set your project properties correctly (set Target Android version and Compile version to Android 7.0 or 7.1). Then see if you still get the same issue. You might also try turning off the linker and see if the issue is still happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a solution:
I opened AndroidManifest.xml file and I removed the android target version property.

Now I have only:

Android compilation version: 7.1
Android miminal version: 4.1