# LinkAssemblies" task failed unexpectedly

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have Xamarin Forms application (https://github.com/xamarinhq/app-evolve) which is working fine when I run in debug mode, but when I try to compile in release Xamarin.Android application in release mode it throws following error.

```
 error MSB4018: The "LinkAssemblies" task failed unexpectedly.
 error MSB4018: Mono.Linker.MarkException: Error processing method: 'System.Void Android.Support.V7.View.WindowCallbackWrapper::n_OnProvideKeyboardShortcuts_Ljava_util_List_Landroid_view_Menu_I(System.IntPtr,System.IntPtr,System.IntPtr,System.IntPtr,System.Int32)' in assembly: 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat.dll' ---> Mono.Cecil.ResolutionException: Failed to resolve Android.Views.KeyboardShortcutGroup
 error MSB4018:    at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.HandleUnresolvedType(TypeReference reference)
 error MSB4018:    at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkType(TypeReference reference)
 error MSB4018:    at MonoDroid.Tuner.MonoDroidMarkStep.MarkType(TypeReference reference)
 error MSB4018:    at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkGenericArguments(IGenericInstance instance)
 error MSB4018:    at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.GetOriginalType(TypeReference type)
 error MSB4018:    at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkType(TypeReference reference)
 error MSB4018:    at MonoDroid.Tuner.MonoDroidMarkStep.MarkType(TypeReference reference)
 error MSB4018:    at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkMethodBody(MethodBody body)
 error MSB4018:    at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessMethod(MethodDefinition method)
 error MSB4018:    at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessQueue()
 error MSB4018:    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
 error MSB4018:    at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessQueue()
 error MSB4018:    at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.Process()
 error MSB4018:    at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.Process(LinkContext context)
 error MSB4018:    at Mono.Linker.Pipeline.Process(LinkContext context)
 error MSB4018:    at MonoDroid.Tuner.Linker.Process(LinkerOptions options, LinkContext& context)
 error MSB4018:    at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.Execute(DirectoryAssemblyResolver res)
 error MSB4018:    at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.Execute()
 error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
 error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext()
```

My minimum android version and target android version is as below.

Minimum and target Android versions

[image]

Comment: You may need to increase your API level to account for the nugets you have referenced for app compat v7. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44086909/the-linkassemblies-task-failed-unexpectedly-on-build-solution-in-release-mode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This API was introduced in API 24, thus you need a minimum of API 24 to compile against. You would need to set your `<TargetFramework>` to 7.0 or higher for this method to be included.

[https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.Callback.html#onProvideKeyboardShortcuts(java.util.List, android.view.Menu, int)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.Callback.html#onProvideKeyboardShortcuts(java.util.List%3Candroid.view.KeyboardShortcutGroup%3E,%20android.view.Menu,%20int))

As a general tip, you should have your `<TargetFramework>` set to the same major version of the support library you are using. For example if you are using v26 of the support library, you would be compiling against API 26.